# Django join on cached queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-cache

I have three models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    video_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author_fk = models.ForeignKey(GRUser, related_name='uploaded_videos', db_column='author_fk')

class VideoLike(models.Model):
    video_like_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    video_fk = models.ForeignKey(Video, related_name='likes_list', db_column='video_fk')
    author_fk = models.ForeignKey(GRUser, related_name='video_likes_list', db_column='author_fk')
    video_like_dttm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class VideoStats(models.Model):
    video_fk_pk = models.OneToOneField(Video, primary_key=True, db_column='video_fk_pk', related_name='stats')
    likes_num = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

To prevent the same database hits I periodically cache some popular videos:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

qs_all = models.Video.objects.select_related('author_fk', 'stats').filter(publication_status=models.Video.PUBLISHED).order_by('-stats__likes_num')

cache.set('popular_videos_all', qs_all[:length])
```

When returning those videos through my API (Django-Rest-Framework) I should add video_like_pk of current user's like if the user is authenticated and the like exists.

I can do it using prefetch_related but it makes two calls to the database and doesn't use the cached results. I want to fetch from the database only VideoLikes of current user and take the rest from the cache. Is it possible? Maybe there is a completely other approach which is better?

Comment: Don't know if optimal solution, but I made my own rest framework list view based on slightly modified ListModelMixin and manually loop through the list of objects and setting extra fields before the list is getting serialized https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35

Comment: @serg how does it differ from simply adding SerializerMethodField? It causes [N +1 select issue](http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/)

Comment: It differs because inside a serializer method you can only access a single current record, so you have to do a number of extra queries equal to a number of records. Inside the custom list view you can see the whole list of rows, so you can loop through them (without hitting db again), collect all ids and then make a single query to db to get them, or whatever postprocessing you need to do.

Comment: @serg it's a good possibility, thanks!